# Ranges in bar graph JFreeChart

Tags: java, netbeans, jfreechart

I have created a graph with JFreeChart and I've been trying to change the ranges on the Y-axis.
I need it to go from 1 to 10, but with intervals of 1 unit. (1,2,3,...,9,10)
I haven't been able to find a way for that, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work

```
    CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) p.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10)); 
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
```